# testing a datetime object or how to use a reader form in code

Tags: clojure

I have the following midje code -

`(fact "Parsing the date received from github"
      (parse-date "2013-02-20T17:24:33Z") => #<DateTime 2013-02-20T17:24:33.000Z>)`

I am trying to test a function which when given a string returns a date time object (joda time using the clj-time lib).

How do I represent the date time object `#<DateTime 2013-02-20T17:24:33.000Z>` in code, so that it doesnt throw error 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unreadable form, compiling:(mashup/github.clj:11)`

Comment: Couldn't understand your question, please elaborate bit more!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clj-time has constructor functions for this:

```
user> (use 'clj-time.core)
nil
user> (date-time 2013 02 20 17 24 33)
#<DateTime 2013-02-20T17:24:33.000Z>
```

so your midje fact would look like:

```
(fact "Parsing the date received from github" (parse-date "2013-02-20T17:24:33Z") 
   => (date-time 2013 02 20 17 24 33))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the #inst reader macro:

```
user=> #inst "2013-02-20T17:24:33.000Z"
#inst "2013-02-20T17:24:33.000-00:00"
```

Comment: +1 for the ans. I couldnt find any doc on #inst, what does it do ?

Comment: I prefer an explicit call to ``date-time`` as per my answer, but this is certainly a valid approach. More info on tagged literals: http://clojure.org/reader#The%20Reader--Tagged%20Literals